# Copy changed files using command file

Tags: tomcat, ant, batch-file, command

I give you an example what I want to do,

I want to configure SSL for tomcat which means, remove comments for SSL configuration part from server.xml in tomcat (or write new if commented configuration is not already present). I want to do it within a program;

I can write a java code and implement the logic but I want to ask if I can do it using some command file where,

I write a bunch of commands in a file and it happens automatically looking for all test cases like if SSL is already configured then don't touch the file etc. In other words, I will change the server.xml file.

I don't know the technology so can I guide me where to start from? Will it be a build file built using Ant? or batch file?

If you need more explanation, i will edit the question. Please add the tag for me if you know any other technology can do it.

P.S. Later on, I would have to do the same thing (changing, copying in xml) for other files like db files etc.

best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at using XSLT: it's built for manipulating XML files.

You can use Ant's `<xslt>` task if you want to script it.

In your XSL template, you can write whatever rules you want for modifying configuration, etc. It might be difficult to detect the SSL configuration within XML comments and remove the surrounding comment delimiters, but you might be able to add an SSL configuration where none is found.